# TableView não atualiza quando adiciono novos valores

Tags: javafx

Bom dia, estou iniciando nesse mundo de java e estou com uma dificuldade que não faço muita ideia de como resolver. Estou criando um cadastro de equipamentos com JavaFX, adiciono e pesquiso valores corretamente porém se acabo de adicionar um valor não consigo pesquisá-lo. Então como poderia atualizar a minha tableview para receber esse valor e posteriormente pesquisá-lo?

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TableColumn<Equipamento, Integer> tbCodigo;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Equipamento, String> tbDescricao;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Equipamento, String> tbStatus;

@FXML
public TableView<Equipamento> tabela;

@FXML
private TextField txNumPatrimonio;

@FXML
private TextField txDescricao;

@FXML
private TextField txStatus;

@FXML
private Label labelNumPatr;

@FXML
private Label labelDescr;

@FXML
private Label labelStatus;

@FXML
private AnchorPane pane2;

@FXML
private TextField txNumPatrConsulta;

@FXML
private TableView<Equipamento> tabelaConsulta;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Equipamento, Integer> tbNumPatrConsulta;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Equipamento, String> tbDescConsulta;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Equipamento, String> tbStatusConsulta;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {           
    carregaTabela();                

    tabela.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> selecionarItemTableViewEquip(newValue));

    System.out.println(" " + listaEquipamentos().get(0).getDescricao());
    System.out.println(" " + listaEquipamentos().get(1).getDescricao());
    System.out.println(" " + listaEquipamentos().get(2).getDescricao());
    System.out.println(" " + listaEquipamentos().get(3).getDescricao());       
}

//adiciona um equipamento;
@FXML
protected void addEquip(ActionEvent event) {
    Integer cod;
    String desc, stat;

    cod = Integer.parseInt(txNumPatrimonio.getText());
    desc = txDescricao.getText();
    stat = txStatus.getText();

    Equipamento e = new Equipamento(cod, desc, stat);
    listaEquipamentos().add(e);
    tabela.getItems().add(e);

    txNumPatrimonio.clear();
    txDescricao.clear();
    txStatus.clear();           
}

@FXML
public void carregaTabela(){    
    tbCodigo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("codigo"));
    tbDescricao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("descricao"));
    tbStatus.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));

    tabela.setItems(listaEquipamentos());
}

//observableList com alguns dados
ObservableList<Equipamento> listaEquipamentos(){
    return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Equipamento(12, "impressora a laser", "Sala 1"),
            new Equipamento(21, "notebook", "Secretaria"),
            new Equipamento(25, "fax", "Cozinha"),
            new Equipamento(31, "cafeteira", "Sala 1")
    );
}    

@FXML
protected void consultarEquip(ActionEvent event){
    ObservableList<Equipamento> listEquips = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Integer cod = Integer.parseInt(txNumPatrConsulta.getText());
    System.out.println(txNumPatrConsulta.getText());

    pane2.setVisible(true);

    listaEquipamentos().forEach((e) -> {
        if(Objects.equals(cod, e.getCodigo())){
            System.out.println(e.getDescricao());
            listEquips.add(e);

        }                       
    });

    tbNumPatrConsulta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("codigo"));
    tbDescConsulta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("descricao"));
    tbStatusConsulta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("status"));

    tabelaConsulta.setItems(listEquips);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deve guardar uma referência ao ObservableList que você colocou como conjunto de itens do seu TableView. Daí quando for adicionar não faça:

```
tabela.getItems().add(e);
```

Todo o CRUD deverá ser feito no ObservableList previamente definido:

```
private ObservableList<Equipamento> listaEquipamentos;
// [...]

protected void addEquip(ActionEvent event) {
    // [...]
    listaEquipamentos.add(new Equipamento(cod, desc, stat));
    // [...]           
}

public void carregaTabela(){    
    // [...]
    tabela.setItems(listaEquipamentos());
}

public void listarEquipamentos(){
    listaEquipamentos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Equipamento(12, "impressora a laser", "Sala 1"),
        new Equipamento(21, "notebook", "Secretaria"),
        new Equipamento(25, "fax", "Cozinha"),
        new Equipamento(31, "cafeteira", "Sala 1")
    );
}
```